# How to remplace CCH (CANCEL CHARACTER) in Marshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Currently I am developing a Java service which converts an class to json string, however when there is any one attribute with the character ” (It is word quotes) then the marshalling process returns **CCH** character (CANCEL CHARACTER) which appears of this way in notepad++ app.

The following code shows that **objectClassX** is the object for transforming:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper=mapper = new ObjectMapper();

byte[] bytesJson= mapper.writeValueAsBytes(objectClassX);
String stringJson = bytesJson!=null?new String(bytesJson , "UTF-8"):"VACIO";
```

I am using the **byteJson** for doing some things, but finnaly it is has been converted to **String**.

I want remplacing the **CCH** character by an blank space, but I would like doing from **ObjectMapper** configuration, and of this way I would avoid doing from **replace** code from **String**.

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Comment: If you get a CCH ['CANCEL CHARACTER' (U+0094)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0094/index.htm), when the real character is a `”` ['RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+201D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm), then if is caused by a mismatch of character sets, because the UTF-8 encoding of `”` is hex `E2 80 9D`. --- Likely, the problem is upstream, where the string values in `objectClassX` comes from.

Comment: Why are you using `writeValueAsBytes` is you want a `String`? Use `writeValueAsString`.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I am using the bytes[] to send it ot outputStream and String for save the logs (it is another song). On the other hand, do you know how can I solve my problem, I would like to remplace CCH from a configuration of  ObjectMapper (with JsonParser.Feature).

Comment: As I said, the problem is likely upstream, where the string values in `objectClassX` comes from. You need to fix that code to not load a CCH character into a field of that object.